# XUbuntu vsftpd couldnt restart

Tags: xubuntu, vsftpd

```
# sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service vsftpd restart

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the stop(8) and then start(8) utilities,
e.g. stop vsftpd ; start vsftpd. The restart(8) utility is also available.
vsftpd start/running, process 3237
```

then I tried this

```
# service vsftpd start
vsftpd start/running, process 3275

# service vsftpd stop
stop: Unknown instance: 

# service vsftpd restart
stop: Unknown instance: 
vsftpd start/running, process 3315


# sudo service vsftpd  restart
stop: Unknown instance: 
vsftpd start/running, process 3358
```

I couldn't get the vsftp resrated when ever I try the restart the above happens ! 
How to restart ?
Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try stopping or killing each instance of `vsftpd` manually before trying to start it again. It looks like you have 4 copies of the server running, the first of which is not managed by upstart. `/etc/init.d/vsftpd stop` might be a good starting point.